# keep getting KieServer-ControllerConnect error 401 in startup (standalone.bat) for Business central

Tags: controller, http-status-code-401, kie-server, kie-wb

I installed `Kie-WB (business central 7.47.0)`  on Wildfly (19.0.0 final) on a windows server.
All is well except that in running the standalone, but I keep getting a warning.

> *WARN  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl]
> (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with
> controller at
> ws://127.0.0.1:8080/kie-wb/websocket/controller/wildfly-kieserver
> error Invalid response code 401*

I have the same installation on my PC where I develop my business rules in KIE-WB. This installation is running without the warnings. I compared the two but can not find the cause of the issue.

As I plan to keep it running 24/7 I would like to get rid of this warning.

Does anyone have the right suggestions?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Solved: find the right place (standalone-full.xml) to set the system properties. and changed the user from management user to app user.